# To show fileinput and actionbutton inline

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I am trying to build an app using R shiny where I am using fileinput and action button in same box. I am facing issues to show above two inline. Refer to below working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Inline Widgets Issue"),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(  
    box(title = "Working Example",width=40 ,status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = FALSE,
        fluidRow(column(width=8,fileInput('file1', 'Browse File',width="100%",
                                           accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'))),
                        column(width=2,actionButton("save","Save!!")))
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Currently this is the situation:
[image]
I want something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a style tag to your action button:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Inline Widgets Issue"),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(  
    box(title = "Working Example",width=40 ,status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = FALSE,
        fluidRow(column(width=8,fileInput('file1', 'Browse File',width="100%",
                                          accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'))),
                 column(width=2,actionButton("save","Save!!"))),
        tags$style(type='text/css', "#save { width:100%; margin-top: 25px;}")
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

you can also play around with width and margin-top to change the size and position of the action button.