# R Shiny - Vertically aligning inline elements (fileInput and actionButton)

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

The app below contains a `fileInput` and `actionButton`. I would like to vertically align the two elements so that the `actionButton` lines up with the `Browse` button of the `fileInput`. In addition to the code included below, I also tried `display:flex` and `align-items:center;` as well as `fluidRow(column(width = 9, ...), column(width = 3, ...))` to no avail. I'm not sure what I'm missing and any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------
ui = fluidPage(

  tagList(

    box(
      width = 5,

      tags$div(style = "display:inline-block; width:75%;",
               fileInput(
                 inputId = 'file',
                 label = 'Select file:',
                 accept = c('.txt', '.csv', '.xls', '.xlsx', '.rds', '.dta', '.sas7bdat', '.sav')
               )
      ),

      tags$div(style = "display:inline-block; width:20%;", 
               div(class = 'pull-right',
                   actionButton('upload', 'Upload')
               )
      )
    )


  )

)

# SERVER ------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @A. Suliman I wanted to display them inline because I didn't want the user to confuse the process of selecting a file with the process of reading it in. Is it not possible to center them vertically?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532088/to-show-fileinput-and-actionbutton-inline). In your case use `#upload` instead of `#save`

Comment: It is possible with a flexbox.